# How do I repeatedly call an API using IDs from a CSV and write the output to a new CSV?

Tags: python, api, csv

I'm trying to pull song data for a hundred different songs from the Echonest API. I have the IDs for each song in a CSV file - I'm trying to write a script that reads the IDs, appends them to the API url, and writes the data to a new CSV, but I'm having a little trouble.

Is there a good way to pull the ID codes and append them to the URL in a loop? This is what I have so far; not sure how/where to put it in the part about adding the IDs to the URL.

```
import urllib2
import json
import csv
from time import sleep
outfile_path='/Users/path/to/file.csv'
api_url = 'http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/profile?'
API_KEY = ''
writer = csv.writer(open(outfile_path))
with open('/Users/path/to/file.csv') as f:
    for row in csv.DictReader(f):
        song_id = row['id']
        qs = urllib.urlencode({"api_key": API_KEY,
                               "bucket": "audio_summary",
                               "id": song_id})
        url = '{}?{}'.format(API_URL, qs)
        parsed_json = json.load(resource)
        for song in parsed_json['results']:
          row = []
          writer.writerow({k: v.encode('utf-8') for k, v in song.items()})
          sleep(5)
```

Comment: Did you want to post some code that works and is correctly formatted? You've got unquoted strings and un-indented `while` blocks at a quick glance....

Comment: What part is causing you trouble? Are you not seeing intended results or running into errors? This is not clear from your post.
On a general note: look into list comprehensions to clean up your code and also consider splitting repetitive stuff off into functions. That makes stuff faster, more maintainable and easier on the eye. I am pretty sure you can do the whole row.append(...) section in one or two lines. Not that shorter is always better, but this may be a prime example.

Comment: What does your input file look like? If it's just ids why are they stored in a csv file?

Comment: As a side note, this code would be about 75% shorter, and more readable and robust, if you used a `csv.DictWriter` instead of trying to build a list out of the dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which part you're stuck on (there are a lot of problems with your posted code that will prevent it from even compiling, much less getting to your real problem, and you haven't described the problem), but there seem to be two likely places.

First, I'm not sure you know how to open a CSV file and get values out of it. You're trying to open a directory rather than a file, and you're not doing anything with the rows, and then you're trying to do the inner loop 100 times for each of your 100 rows when I'm 99% sure you just want to do it once for each of your 100 rows.

If you use `csv.reader`, you have to know which column number the IDs are in; it's a lot easier with a `csv.DictReader`, because you only have to know what that column name is. So, let's do that:

```
with open('/path/to/inputfile.csv') as f:
    for row in csv.DictReader(f):
        song_id = row['id']
        # make and process request with song_id
```

If your CSV file doesn't have a header row, then just use a `reader`, and put the column number (e.g., `0` for the first column) in place of `'id'`.

---

Now, what you want to do with that ID is to stick each one in a URL. You can do that by using string formatting. For example:

```
URL_TEMPLATE = 'http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/profile?api_key=&bucket=audio_summary&id={}'

# ... inside the for loop ...
song_id = row['id']
url = URL_TEMPLATE.format(song_id)
resource = urllib2.urlopen(url)
parsed_json = json.load(resource)
```

You're also going to need to fill in your `api_key`, or EchoNest won't accept your query, so:

```
URL_TEMPLATE = 'http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/profile?api_key={}&bucket=audio_summary&id={}'
API_KEY = "<your API key goes here>"

# ... inside the for loop ...
url = URL_TEMPLATE.format(API_KEY, song_id)
```

However, it's usually better to use [`urlencode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) to generate a query string, instead of trying to do it through string methods. Besides being more readable, that will take care of things you probably haven't even thought of, like encoding any URL-unfriendly characters in your values. So:

```
API_URL = 'http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/profile'

# ... inside the for loop ...
qs = urllib.urlencode({"api_key": API_KEY, 
                       "bucket": "audio_summary",
                       "id": song_id})
url = '{}?{}'.format(API_URL, qs)
```

---

And then you just need the part that loops over `parsed_join['results']` and writes out rows, which you've already written. But two notes on that.

First, `str(foo.encode('utf-8'))` is unnecessary; `encode` already returns a `str`.

Second, you've got a whole lot of unnecessary repeated code to build up that `row`. You're doing the same thing for each key in the `song` dict, so why not just use a `DictWriter` and leave it as a dict:

```
writer.writerow({k: v.encode('utf-8') for k, v in song.items()})
```

… or, if you prefer to use `writer`, just use `operator.itemgetter` to fetch them all at once into a list:

```
writer.writerow(v.encode('utf-8') for v in itemgetter(headers)(song))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I revised my code to reflect your suggestions; I am getting a weird error when I try to run the script however: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/path/to/file.py", line 5, in <module>
    import csv
  File "/Users/path/to/file.py", line 8
    url_template = ''http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/profile?api_key=&bucket=audio_summary&id={}''`

Comment: @user2766455: It's generally pretty hard to debug a problem from half a traceback without the error message, especially when posted in SO comments (which lose all the formatting). Post the entire thing, including the error message, somewhere—if it's a new problem, create a new question; if it's a simple followup, edit your existing question; if neither seems appropriate, put it on pastebin or gist and put a link in a comment.

Comment: @user2766455: However, looking at what you did post… it looks like you have two single quotes around your `url_template` value, which is an obvious `SyntaxError`.